# getting "class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found" error after updating firebase libraries

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[image]

PFB the entries I am having in `build.gradle` file:

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'
```

I am also getting below warning in build.gradle file even though all versions are same.

[image]

Project level build file is having below entries

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

All the version codes of firebase libraries are same. How this issue can be resolved?

Comment: hi, do you use multidex application or not?